# How to save state of initial data in behaviorsubject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have initial array of roles in `private roles$ = new BehaviorSubject<Role[]>([]);` loaded from server.

I read `roles$` and map to local variable inside component:

```
public localRoles: Observable<Role[]>;
this.localRoles = this.service.roles$;
```

There is also method `checkAll()` that changes `roles$`. How to save initial state of `roles$` after any changes?

```
checkAll() {
  this.localRoles.pipe(map((l) => { l.checked = true; return l;});
}
```

So, when change `this.localRoles` I want to merge it with `roles$` to get last changes.

But in some places I still need to get initial state(without chanegs) of `roles$`.

I have found one solution, what do you think about that?:

```
this.localRoles = this.service.roles$.pipe(
            map((roles: Role[])=> {
                  if(CHANGES$.getValue()) return CHANGES$.getValue();
                  return roles;
            }),
        );
```

Store chnages in another stream `CHANGES$` then when read state of exist if not return initial state.

Comment: What do you mean by saving the initial sate of roles$? couldn't you map it to a variable "initialRoles" ?

Comment: I mean when I first get data I push it to `BehaviorSubject` then in some places of app I map this data. So at any time I need to get initial state of `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: I can fill another behSubject by modified version of roles$, then somehow merge them

Comment: I don't understand, the role of behavior subjects is to save the current state, whenever you want the the value you can call this.service.roles.value, or you can subscribe to it and get the value if it's changing.

Comment: What you are trying to do? update your question with more details of what are trying to achieve, and elaborate about your case.

Comment: Okay, 2 minutes It was updated.

Comment: If you are changing roles$ then you should load the initial state in a variable (you can create a service that fetch the data and have getter and setter for roles$ and getter and setter for the initial state variable). But, if you are not changing role$, obviously you are not, then there is not need of all of that, whenever you want the initial state just call role$.value (because you are changing localRoles only, as I noticed)

Comment: Okay, but how to get data based initial state with changes? We git that initial state we can get calling roles$

Comment: I need something like this: A state (initail). B state(changes). Render B state if exist esle render A state.

Comment: Now I get always initial state after loading component

Comment: if you want to persist data on page refresh you would need to store it somewhere, like localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can do something like this. It uses the scan operator to maintain the list of cart items.

(This app is a shopping cart and has the ability to add, update, or delete items in the cart.)

```
  // Add item action (Actions: Add, update, delete)
  private itemSubject = new Subject<Action<CartItem>>();
  itemAction$ = this.itemSubject.asObservable();

  cartItems$ = this.itemAction$
    .pipe(
      scan((items, itemAction) => this.modifyCart(items, itemAction), [] as CartItem[])
    );
```

Here are the routines that emit the Action based on the user action:

```
  // Add the vehicle to the cart as an Action<CartItem>
  addToCart(vehicle: Vehicle): void {
    this.itemSubject.next({
      item: { vehicle, quantity: 1 },
      action: 'add'
    });
  }

  // Remove the item from the cart
  removeFromCart(cartItem: CartItem): void {
    this.itemSubject.next({
      item: { vehicle: cartItem.vehicle, quantity: 0 },
      action: 'delete'
    });
  }

  updateInCart(cartItem: CartItem, quantity: number) {
    this.itemSubject.next({
      item: { vehicle: cartItem.vehicle, quantity },
      action: 'update'
    });
  }
```

And here is the method that performs the appropriate operation on the emitted array of cart items:

```
  // Return the updated array of cart items
  private modifyCart(items: CartItem[], operation: Action<CartItem>): CartItem[] {
    if (operation.action === 'add') {
      return [...items, operation.item];
    } else if (operation.action === 'update') {
      return items.map(item => item.vehicle.name === operation.item.vehicle.name ? operation.item : item)
    } else if (operation.action === 'delete') {
      return items.filter(item => item.vehicle.name !== operation.item.vehicle.name);
    }
    return [...items];
  }
```

Basically, every time the user selects to add an item to the cart, a new array is created that includes the new item and the new array is emitted.

When the user selects to update, the item is located in the array and replaced with the updated item.

When the user selects to delete, the array is filtered to include all *but* that deleted item.

NOTE: The end point I was using had no Ids, so is using the vehicle name as a key (which is not normally a great idea).

Is this close to what you are trying to do?